# Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 sending compressed file to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails API application running on Ruby 2.0.0 that accepts XML files. When I send the file uncompressed using curl `--data-binary` it works fine but when I send it compressed it blows up going through Rack utils.

**CURL command**

`curl -u user:password --compressed -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" --data-binary "@reading.xml.gz" http://localhost:3002/readings`

**Error stack trace**

```
  ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/utils.rb:104:in `normalize_params'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/utils.rb:96:in `block in parse_nested_query'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/utils.rb:93:in `each'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/utils.rb:93:in `parse_nested_query'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/request.rb:373:in `parse_query'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:321:in `parse_query'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/request.rb:211:in `POST'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:282:in `POST'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:16:in `parameters'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_parameters.rb:37:in `filtered_parameters'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'

...
```

I put a debugger on the relevant line in rack utils and if I `force_encode` to binary I can get through but why is the encoding changing at all?

UPDATE 1: Added CURL output

```
== Info: Adding handle: conn: 0x7fb78c010800
== Info: Adding handle: send: 0
== Info: Adding handle: recv: 0
== Info: Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
== Info: - Conn 0 (0x7fb78c010800) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
== Info: About to connect() to localhost port 3002 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 127.0.0.1...
== Info: Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3002 (#0)
== Info: Server auth using Basic with user '1'
=> Send header, 254 bytes (0xfe)
0000: POST /readings HTTP/1.1
001c: Authorization: Basic
005c: ycg==
0063: User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
007c: Host: localhost:3002
0092: Accept: */*
009f: Content-Length: 1154
00b5: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
00e6: Expect: 100-continue
00fc: 
== Info: Done waiting for 100-continue
=> Send data, 1154 bytes (0x482)
0000: ....)v.L..reading.xml...Qo.8...O...{/$N.6..R..Zi[...>.V....]
0040: H..P.........{...Fu<.....v.*.L.`....._</..l...Y..L.....z?..w....
0080: ./L|..*.....o...i.I...<..o.Y...o...}..r...?..xR-EU.I...o.&_..L|.
00c0: 5..-..I..x......"...:]~..M........0... .0..0.z....T.....W+N.(.z.
0100: 0.TAd....l&.d....h...x.G....m....U3.W..BO.n...MUgE.... ..:.KeH{.
0140: R.v.........GR=2Z.7r....k*.5H.v....`..wd'.Ug.......~:..L..r...Fi
0180: l.D.V.'......M..9...T~'`...t)...k>V...s..._._.c#."_..:.W5.....3.
01c0: .}..T2-j.f>E^r'....:J'..^..7$5"7..`.F.......TG..[.MF@s9.GH.B.M,.
0200: j..y.<.hH.8..Ve.N/y.e4....b..ac.P1.j..h....y<I.../_...w.L=..m...
0240: ....D=.....G....k7...(..M.s{.=....4}...eO...2.?...F]Da....:.$.q
0280: ..{...0.F.8.Hu.[.?..Z...V....`Z.E....<.M|7l...<..Y....E.By.....m
02c0: ..*....y.U3.YZs&o-uJ....yc..M.....I...gksq....Rm&...I.....s.^D~.
0300: W....h/r..........R.h..va......B.;./{H|....w.i.r..szZU.m..$....s
0340: .....].*.......Jzlx<..OnlT:t..3....".Gj{...ve...<...*.Bq..Q.E...
0380: ...Z....@..A.).?).N;.K..p...,......Q.9@.@s.1.1..`.0.....-..]....
03c0: ....Q..q...s.....B.......2....A2H.. .$.d...A2H.. .$.d...A2H.. .
0400: $.d...A2H.. .$.d...A2H.. .$.d...A2H.. .$.d...A2H.. .$..&....6O?.
0440: ....D...x.qt..........................cS.K...>..?........?....\
0480: ..
<= Recv header, 36 bytes (0x24)
0000: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
<= Recv header, 52 bytes (0x34)
0000: X-Request-Id: 23dce9ed-4245-41b2-8c06-024a7b3bf37a
<= Recv header, 21 bytes (0x15)
0000: X-Runtime: 0.026871
<= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: Content-Length: 13032
== Info: HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 13032 bytes (0x32e8)
0000: The standard rails stack trace HTML page went here.

== Info: Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Are you setting the request content type to a compressed type?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of your `curl` invocation with `--trace-ascii -` appended (note the trailing dash for STDOUT.)

Comment: I updated the question with the ascii trace.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares do you mean by setting HTTP headers? -H "Content-encoding: gzip" didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to simulate a form upload and want to the uploaded data to be available in `params`, you need to invoke cURL appropriately:

```
curl --trace-ascii - -u user:password --compressed --form "reading=@reading.xml.gz" http://localhost:3002/readings
```

This will make the uploaded file contents available by calling `params[:reading].read`.

The command you're invoking sends a raw gzipped file as the POST contents, which fails to parse with the indicated Content-Type (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). If you want to manually receive this upload (perhaps by calling `request.body.read` yourself), set the `Content-Type` appropriately so Rails doesn't try to parse the body as a form upload:

```
curl --trace-ascii - -u user:password --compressed -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" --data-binary "@test-deployment.txt.gz" http://localhost:3002/readings
```

There's a bit more discussion [in this question's answers](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request) that will likely point you in the right direction.

Comment: The solution for me was defining the Content-Type header. Thanks for the help!